# Probability density function of $X + Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ has probability density function $f$ and $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$. Supposing they are independent, find the pdf of $X + Y$.

I started by observing that $f_X(x)f_Y(z-x) = 0$ if $z < x$ or $z - 1 > x$ and thus

$$f_{X + Y}(z) = \int_{z-1}^z f \,dx.$$

The trouble is I don't know how to simplfiy this further. I did write it as $F(z) - F(z - 1)$ where $F$ is the CDF of $X$, but that didn't really get me anywhere. Is it possible to do any further simplification?

Comment: You cannot do anything more since $f$ is not given.

Comment: It is correct if you already get $f_Z(z)=F_X(z)-F_X(z-1)$, and it is finished.